# Aa student takes a $10$-question true/false exam and guesses. What is the probability that the student answers every question incorrectly?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, binomial-distribution

> Suppose a student takes a $10$-question true/false exam and guesses at every question.
>   What is the probability that...
>   a) the student answers every question incorrectly?
>   b) the students answers at least one question correctly?
>   c) the student answers exactly 5 questions correctly?

So far I have solved a. I got $(1/2)^{10}$.
For b I'm not sure what to do.
For c would the answer be $(1/2)^5$?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a) Is fine.

b) Notice that the complementary event of $A =$"at least one right" is $\bar A =$"all wrong". Hence
$$P(A) = 1-P(\bar A) = 1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{10}.$$

c) No. You have to count all the spots where you got them right. Notice that there are $\binom{10}{5}$ ways to choose the questions that are correct. We also know that $5$ are wrong (with chance $1/2$ each time) and $5$ are right (with chance $1/2$ each time). Hence
$$P(\text{Exactly 5 right}) = \binom{10}{5}\left(\frac12\right)^5\left(\frac12\right)^5.$$

The number of correct answers in $10$ tries follows a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Answer (score 2):

Given that the probability of answering a question correctly is $\dfrac12$:

---

> a) the student answers every question incorrectly?

$$\left(1-\frac12\right)^{10}$$

---

> b) the students answers at least one question correctly?

$$1-\left(1-\frac12\right)^{10}$$

---

> c) the student answers exactly 5 questions correctly?

$$\binom{10}{5}\cdot\left(\frac12\right)^{5}\cdot\left(1-\frac12\right)^{10-5}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be a random variable that maps the number of correct answers guessed to its probability. $X$ is discrete and thus $X \sim Bionomial(n=10, p = \frac{1}{2})$. Just plug in the corresponding $P(X = a)$ and calculate via. the binomial distribution equation to compute your desired answer. For part b it is $P(X \geq 1) = 1 - P(X =0)$

Answer (score 1):

For b it will be $$\sum\frac{{10\choose i}}{2^{10}}$$ where $ i \in [1,10]$ as its atleast 1 correct . For c it will be any $5$ from $10$ so it will be $$\frac{{10\choose 5}}{2^{10}}$$